# Trying to access Realm Object from an interface

Tags: android, interface, realm

I am using Realm, and i created an interface to parse RealmObject in my Adapter to be implemented in an activity but i get this error

```
**Object is no longer valid to operate on. Was it deleted by another thread?**
```

This is my Code below.

NewsAdapter.java

```
public class TestNewsAdapter extends RealmBaseRecyclerViewAdapter<NewsTrend, TestNewsAdapter.PostsViewHolder> {

public RealmResults<NewsTrend> realmResults;
public Context context;
public EventListener eventListener;
static  String fbid;
private User user;

boolean isFav;



public TestNewsAdapter(Context context, RealmResults<NewsTrend> realmResults,
                       boolean automaticUpdate, User user) {
    super(context, realmResults, automaticUpdate);
    this.realmResults = realmResults;
    this.context = context;
    this.user = user;
}

public void setEventListener(EventListener eventListener) {
    this.eventListener = eventListener;
}

@Override
public PostsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
    fbid = user.getId();
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_news, viewGroup, false);
    PostsViewHolder mediaViewHolder = new PostsViewHolder(v);
    return mediaViewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final PostsViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    final NewsTrend postsData = getItem(position);

    holder.itemView.setTag(postsData);

    String eventName = postsData.getTitle();
    String eventDate = postsData.getTimestamp();
    holder.sourceName.setText(postsData.getType());
    Spanned decodedTitle = Html.fromHtml(eventName);

    holder.tvCountPageView.setText(postsData.getRead_count() + " Views");
    holder.tvNewsCountLike.setText(""+ postsData.getLike_count());

    holder.tvNewsTitle.setText(decodedTitle);
    holder.tvNewsDate.setText(getSplitDate(eventDate));
    String text = postsData.getContent() + "<font color='red'>  <strong>More...</strong></font>";
    holder.tvNewsShortText.setText(Html.fromHtml(text), TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);

    if (postsData.getType().equals("Bella Naija")) {
        holder.sourceImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.bella);
    } else if (postsData.getType().equals("Punch")) {
        holder.sourceImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.punch);
    } else if (postsData.getType().equals("Linda Ikeji")) {
        holder.sourceImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.lib);
    } else if (postsData.getType().equals("Pulse")) {
        holder.sourceImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.pulse_logo);
    }
    // holder.sourceName.setText(postsData.getType());

    Glide.with(context)
            .load(postsData.getImage())
            .centerCrop()
            .placeholder(R.drawable.tw_logo)
            .into(holder.ivNewsImage);



    if (postsData.getLike_status() == 1) {
        holder.ivLike.setImageResource(R.drawable.kalp_dolu_kucuk);
    } else {
        holder.ivLike.setImageResource(R.drawable.kalp_bos_kucuk);
    }


    if (postsData.getArch_status() == 1) {
        Log.d("logFavourite", String.valueOf(postsData.getLike_status()));
        holder.ivFavorite.setImageResource(R.drawable.yildiz_dolu_kucuk);
        this.isFav = true;
    } else {
        holder.ivFavorite.setImageResource(R.drawable.yildiz_bos_kucuk);
        this.isFav = false;
    }

    holder.llRight.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View v) {
            eventListener.onItemClick(v, postsData);
        }
    });


    holder.ivShare.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String shareBody = postsData.getHref();

            Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
            sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Trending App");
            sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
            context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Paylaş"));
        }
    });

    holder.ivFavorite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            eventListener.onFavClick(v,postsData,holder.ivFavorite, isFav);
        }
    });

    holder.ivLike.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            eventListener.onLikeClick(v, postsData, holder.tvNewsCountLike, holder.ivLike);
        }
    });

}




@Override
public NewsTrend getItem(int i) {
    return realmResults.get(i);
}

public void swapData(RealmResults<NewsTrend> realmResults) {
    this.realmResults = realmResults;
}

@Override
public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return realmResults.size();
}

public static class PostsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public RobotoTextView tvNewsDate;
    public RobotoTextView tvNewsTitle;
    public RobotoTextView tvNewsShortText;
    public RobotoTextView sourceName;
    public ImageView sourceImg;

    RelativeLayout postContentHolder;



    public LinearLayout llLeft;
    public LinearLayout llRight;

    public ImageView ivArrowLeft;
    public ImageView ivArrowRight;

    public ImageView ivNewsImage;

    public ImageView ivShare;

    public ImageView ivFavorite;
    public ImageView ivLike;

    public TextView tvCountPageView;
    public TextView tvNewsCountLike;

    PostsViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        postContentHolder = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.postContentHolder);
        ivNewsImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivNewsImage);
        ivArrowLeft = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivArrowLeft);
        ivArrowRight = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivArrowRight);
        llLeft = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.llLeft);
        llRight = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.llRight);

        ivShare = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivShare);
        sourceImg = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.sourceImg);
        sourceName = (RobotoTextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.sourceName);
        tvNewsTitle = (RobotoTextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvNewsTitle);
        tvNewsShortText = (RobotoTextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvNewsShortText);
        tvNewsDate = (RobotoTextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvNewsDate);

        ivFavorite = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivFavorite);
        ivLike = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivLike);

        tvNewsCountLike = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvNewsCountLike);
        tvCountPageView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvCountPageView);

    }
}

public interface EventListener {
    void onItemClick(final View view, NewsTrend postsData);

    void onLikeClick(final View view, NewsTrend postsDAta, TextView tvNewsCountLike,
                     ImageView ivLike);

    void onFavClick(final View view, NewsTrend postData, ImageView ivArchive, boolean isArchive);

}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position;
}

public String getSplitDate(String dateString){

     return dateString;
  }
}
```

Then the implementation in the Fragment class

```
@Override
public void onLikeClick(View view, NewsTrend postData, TextView tvNewsCountLike,
                        ImageView ivLike) {
    if (!postData.isChecked()) {
        realm.beginTransaction();
        postData.setChecked(true);
        realm.commitTransaction();
        tvNewsCountLike.setText("" + (Integer.parseInt(tvNewsCountLike.getText().toString()) + 1));
        ivLike.setImageResource(R.drawable.kalp_dolu_kucuk);
    } else {
        realm.beginTransaction();
        postData.setChecked(false);
        realm.commitTransaction();
        tvNewsCountLike.setText("" + (Integer.parseInt(tvNewsCountLike.getText().toString()) - 1));
        ivLike.setImageResource(R.drawable.kalp_bos_kucuk);
    }
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    like(postData.getNews_id());
}
```

the postsData in the interface returns,

**Object is no longer valid to operate on. Was it deleted by another thread?**

Comment: What is your realm version?

Comment: io.realm:realm-android:0.85.0

Comment: Any reason why you never updated to at least 0.87.5? It doesn't use the Gradle plugin (introduced in 0.88.0) and didn't have a bunch of breaking changes yet,  and it's much more stable.

Comment: If I upgrade will it work fine

Comment: Where do you open/close your Realm instance? While it won't fix your particular issue, 0.87.2 had a fix for a bug that kept me at 0.82.2 for way too long. Although the latest version is at 1.2.0, don't forget that either. It's just that you'd run into the 0.89.0 breaking changes really heavily.

Comment: Inside the fragment

Comment: Oncreate and Ondestroy

Comment: While I do think that **should** work, you should put them in `onCreateView()` and `onDestroyView()` instead.

Comment: Ok, i would do that now, however how you help me, how do you think i can approach this issue to make it solve, i really need to move on

Comment: It looks like the bug fixed by https://github.com/realm/realm-java/pull/2990 . So please update to the latest version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to solve the problem by updating Realm from

```
io.realm:realm-android:0.85.0
```

to the current version using grade plugin.